# Dashboard Filtered by "Ask User"

Tags: reporting

I want to filter a dashboard by customer account number so that I can see all of the reports by just that customer.  I have thousands of customers so setting up a dashboard filter with just 10 isn't the best option because I don't want to give the user just 10 customers to choose from.  Is there a dynamic filter that I can use where they can enter an account number instead of selecting an account number from a prepopulated list?

Comment: How many dashboard items?  Would you be better off putting the dashboard elements on the actual record so when you look at the account, it displays the appropriate elements on that customer's page?

Comment: I guess what @HomerJ is talking about is **Report Charts**. Take a look here for more info https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_embed_pagelayout.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Yup.  They work really well.